# How to use Context.Request.Body and retain it?

Tags: go, go-gin

I am trying to write a middleware where I will be doing a json schema validation against the request body. After the validation, I need to use the request body again. But I am not able to figure out how this can be done. I referred [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911579/gin-golang-empty-req-body)
and found a way to access the body. But once the request body is used, I need that available to my next function.

Here is the sample code:

```
package main
import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "net/http"
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
        //"github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema"
)

func middleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
 return func(c *gin.Context) {
    //Will be doing json schema validation here

    body := c.Request.Body
    x, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(body)

    fmt.Printf("%s \n", string(x))

    fmt.Println("I am a middleware for json schema validation")

    c.Next()
    return
 }
}    

type E struct {
 Email    string
 Password string
}

func test(c *gin.Context) {
 //data := &E{}
 //c.Bind(data)
 //fmt.Println(data)   //prints empty as json body is already used
 
 body := c.Request.Body
 x, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(body)

 fmt.Printf("body is: %s \n", string(x))
 c.JSON(http.StatusOK, c)
}

func main() {
 router := gin.Default()

 router.Use(middleware())

 router.POST("/test", test)

 //Listen and serve
 router.Run("127.0.0.1:8080")
}
```

Current output:

```
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "123"
} 

I am a middleware for json schema validation
body is:
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "123"
} 
I am a middleware for json schema validation
body is: {
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "123"
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/N_553jVAIX shows several variations of duplicating an `io.ReadCloser` in an HTTP handler. The details of what is being done to the body and the expected size would be needed to pick between them.

Answer (score 7):

What Thellimist said, but in more words.

You need to "catch and restore" the Body.
The Body is a buffer, that means that once you read it, its gone. So, if you catch it and "put it back", you can access it again.

Check this answer, I think this is what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295689/3521313

Answer (score 0):

You could copy req.Body inside your middleware. Check out [io.TeeReader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader) + [bytes.Buffer](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer).

As far as I know you can't directly copy an io.Reader so you must copy it while you read it then assign the copied one back to `c.Request.Body` to be able to use it for `c.Bind`

I'm not sure but maybe [this](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/deepcopy) can make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the body content multiple times and you're also using gin-gonic, I think the `ShouldBindBodyWith` function is what you're looking for.

> ShouldBindBodyWith is similar with ShouldBindWith, but it stores the request body into the context, and reuse when it is called again.
>
> NOTE: This method reads the body before binding. So you should use ShouldBindWith for better performance if you need to call only once.

References:

- https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1078
- https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ShouldBindBodyWith