# Go-Gin read request body many times

Tags: go, go-gin

I am trying to restore the context with it's data after performing validation on it's data.I need the data to keep moving as need it later on in the next function.

I am new to golang and the below code is as far I could go. any help and a better approach is much appreciated.

thanks in advance.

the validation middleware

```
func SignupValidator(c *gin.Context) {
    // Read the Body content
    // var bodyBytes []byte
    // if c.Request.Body != nil {
    //  bodyBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    // }
    var user entity.User
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&user); err != nil {
         validate := validator.New()
         if err := validate.Struct(&user); err != nil {
              c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
                 "error": err.Error(),
          })
          c.Abort()
          return
        }
        // c.Request.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))
    }
    // Read the Body content
    var bodyBytes []byte
    if c.Request.Body != nil {
        bodyBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bodyBytes)) // this empty
    c.Next()

}
```

route

```
auth.POST("login", gin.Logger(), validations.SignupValidator, func(ctx *gin.Context) {
            ctx.JSON(200, videoController.Save(ctx))
        })
```

Comment: What you mean by _restoring context_ ?

Comment: well when I read context once while doing validation I can't read that data again, and I need to perform other things after that validation middleware @Зелёный

Comment: You can read body many times, c.ShouldBindJSON is exactly about this. Show error you have.

Comment: the error is after **c.ShouldBindJSON** if you try to access data in the context it will be empty. from this [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186741/how-to-get-the-json-from-the-body-of-a-request-on-go/47295689#47295689) @Зелёный

Comment: Please show full error message.

Comment: I edited the code, tried to log the context data. check it out @Зелёный

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an example of reading body twice with [`ShouldBindBodyWith`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ShouldBindBodyWith), check it:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding"
)

type ParamsOne struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
}

type ParamsTwo struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
}

func main() {
    r := gin.New()
    r.POST("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var f ParamsOne
        // Read ones
        if err := c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&f, binding.JSON); err != nil {
            log.Printf("%+v", err)
        }
        log.Printf("%+v", f)
        var ff ParamsTwo
        
        if err := c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&ff, binding.JSON); err != nil {
            log.Printf("%+v", err)
        }
        log.Printf("%+v", ff)
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, f)
    })
    r.Run(":4000")
}
```

Output:

```
$example: ./example
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
 - using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
 - using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

[GIN-debug] POST   /                         --> main.main.func1 (1 handlers)
[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on :4000
2020/07/05 10:47:03 {Username:somename}
2020/07/05 10:47:03 {Username:somename}
```

Comment: that what I am trying to say, it won't work. because you can't read buffers twice, and you already did read it with `ShouldBindJSON`. try to run that if possible to see if it prints something, because it doesn't on my side.

Comment: To other readers: `ShouldBindJSON` and `ShouldBindBodyWith` behave differently. You can't call `ShouldBindJSON` twice, but `ShouldBindBodyWith` won't run into the same issue. If you really do need to manually read the body twice, @spehlivan's answer below should do the trick.

Comment: Supporting @MicFok comment, link to official docs - https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/bind-body-into-dirrerent-structs/

Answer (score 23):

You can try this.

```
ByteBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
c.Request.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(ByteBody))
```

You can then use ByteBody however you want without side-effects on `c.Request.Body`

Comment: Make sure to handle the ioutil.ReadAll's error. Using underscore is not recommended in Go, because byteBody can be nil. and the server might panic.

Answer (score 2):

As @Philidor has shown `ShouldBindBodyWith` should do the trick, in my case I decided to go with something similar to @spehlivan, because of two reasons:

- `ShouldBindBodyWith` requires that the following binds are also ShouldBindBodyWith, it means I need to change all my previous code, which uses `c.Bind`
- You need to explicitly tell to S`houldBindBodyWith` the binding type you are trying to do, JSON, Form, ProtoBuf, etc, other binds like `c.Bind` detects it automatically.

This is what it looks like:

```golang
var input models.SomeInput

bodyCopy := new(bytes.Buffer)
// Read the whole body
_, err := io.Copy(bodyCopy, c.Request.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Error reading API token"})
    c.Abort()
    return
}
bodyData := bodyCopy.Bytes()

// Replace the body with a reader that reads from the buffer
c.Request.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(bodyData))

err = c.Bind(&input)

// Some code here...

// Replace the body with a reader that reads from the buffer
c.Request.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(bodyData))
```

Pay attention I replaced the `c.Request.Body` twice, for the bind in that code snippet and then at the end, for the next bind, in another place of my code (this snippet is from a middleware, the next bind is called from the controller).

In my case I needed to do this because the API Token is sent in the request body, which I don't recommend, it should be sent in the request header.

Answer (score 0):

There are trickier situations where `ShouldBindBodyWith` alone might not help.

I have a middleware that needs to perform a raw read of the request body, not a binding with a struct, to check its integrity against a HMAC-256 signature. Unfortunately, as the request body is a `ReadCloser`, once the reader has consumed all the bytes, any further attempt to reread them inevitably leads to an EOF error.

As a consequence, if the following handlers wanted to perform a proper binding, even using `ShouldBindBodyWith` method the binding would fail with the above error.

Looking at both the `ShouldBindBodyWith` documentation and implementation, I noticed that it performs the real reading only once and cache the read bytes into the context.

Since the cache key is public, I have managed to solve my particular issue by saving the result of my raw reading, performed using the usual `io.ReadAll`, and set it into the cache:

```golang
func MyMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        payload, err := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
        if err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        c.Set(gin.BodyBytesKey, payload)

        // Do my stuff with payload bytes

        c.Next()
    }
}

func MyHandler() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var bindingErr error
        var requestBodyFirstRead myFirstPotentialPayloadBindingType
        if bindingErr = c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&requestBodyFirstRead); bindingErr != nil {
            var requestBodySecondRead mySecondPotentialPayloadBindingType
            if bindingErr = c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&requestBodySecondRead); bindingErr != nil {
                c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, bindingErr).SetType(gin.ErrorTypeBind)
            }
        }

        if bindingErr != nil {
            return
        }

        // Do your handler stuff
    }
}
```